# make django-social-auth work

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I wanna use django-social-auth in my website,but I'm totally confused by [documentation](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/),
I have several questions:

1. how can i find such information : TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
   TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
   FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
   FACEBOOK_API_SECRET,... , I tryed to use this [documentation](http://hueniverse.com/category/oauth/) but no result.
2. and where is a documentation that describes the template and view parts to handle authentications in diffrent backends

sorry!maybe my question is nonsense but I really have problem with documentation!

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using Twitter and Facebook's API, you need to create an application with both of them to gain access to their respective APIs

`TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY` and `TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET` are provided to you when you register your application/website with Twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

and similarly `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_API_SECRET` etc. are provided to you when you register an app with Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

If you want to see what templates you need to create along with what settings etc., have a look at the example project that is included with the source

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example

You can browse the source itself to the views and urls used:

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/social_auth

Comment: tnx so much,I will check them out